# No puedo aplicar filtros a imagenes

Tags: java, imagen

espero que me puedan ayudar, he estado trabajando en un proyecto en el que tengo que hacer un programa donde aplique filtros (en específico RGB, sepia, escala de grises y BYN).
El problema es que a la hora de intentar mostrar la imagen con el filtro ya aplicado me tira un error que dice que la imagen es nula, soy nuevo en el manejo de imagenes y no sé qué puedo hacer
Pongo también los códigos para los filtros ya que creo que el error también se encuentra ahí.
Llevo ya un rato atascado y realmente no puedo pensar en una solución que me haya podido ayudar

Muchas gracias por su atención
Aquí mi código

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


 public class menuu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JFileChooser seleccionado = new JFileChooser();
File archivo;
byte [] bytesImg;
MET gestion = new MET();

ImageIcon imagenSeleccionada;
BufferedImage imgsel;
JSlider spromedio;
/**
 * Creates new form menuu
 */
public menuu() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

             

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    camara si = new camara();
    si.setVisible(true);
    entrada.close();
}                                        

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String op = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesImg);
    BufferedImage newBi;
    try {
        newBi = ImageIO.read(is);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(menuu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
      
    if (op.equals("Blanco y negro"))
    {
    newBi = aplicarFiltroBYN();
    BufferedImage b = newBi;
    if (b != null)
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(b));
    }
    
     if (op.equals("Escala de grises"))
    {
        newBi = aplicarFiltroESDG();
    BufferedImage b = newBi;
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon (b));
    }
     
      if (op.equals("Sepia"))
    {
        newBi = aplicarFiltrosep();
    BufferedImage b = newBi;
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon (b));
    }
      
       if (op.equals("RGB"))
    {
        newBi = aplicarFiltroRGB();
    BufferedImage b = newBi;
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon (b));
    }
   
}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
            if (seleccionado.showDialog(null, "Abrir archivo")== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
        if (archivo.canRead())
        {
                if (archivo.getName().endsWith("jpg")||archivo.getName().endsWith("png")||archivo.getName().endsWith("gif"))
                {
                    bytesImg = gestion.AbrirImagen(archivo);
                    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bytesImg));
                   jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bytesImg));
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione un formato de imagen válido");
                }
        }
    }
}                                        

public BufferedImage aplicarFiltroESDG() {
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    if(imgsel != null ) {
        bi = new BufferedImage(imgsel.getWidth(), imgsel.getHeight(),2);
        Color colorImagen; int gris = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < imgsel.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (imgsel.getHeight()-1); j++) {
                colorImagen = new Color(imgsel.getRGB(i, j), true);
                gris =(int) ( (colorImagen.getRed() * .299) + 
                (colorImagen.getGreen() * .114) + (colorImagen.getBlue() * .587) ); 
                colorImagen = new Color(gris, gris, gris, 
       (gris > 230)?0:255);
             bi.setRGB(i, j, colorImagen.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    return bi;
}

   public BufferedImage aplicarFiltroBYN() {
   BufferedImage bi = null;
 if (imgsel != null) {
  bi = new BufferedImage(imgsel.getWidth(), imgsel.getHeight(),
  BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
  for (int x = 0; x < imgsel.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < imgsel.getHeight(); y++) {
   Color c = new Color(imgsel.getRGB(x, y));
  int r=c.getRed();
  int g=c.getGreen();
 int b=c.getBlue();
 if(r<spromedio.getValue()){
  r=0;
 }else{
  r=255;
 }
 if(g<spromedio.getValue()){
  g=0;
 }else{
  g=255;
 }
 if(b<spromedio.getValue()){
  b=0;
 }else{
  b=255;
 }
 bi.setRGB(x, y, new Color(r, g, b).getRGB());
}
}
}
 return bi;
}

public BufferedImage aplicarFiltrosep() {
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    if(imgsel != null ) {
        bi = new BufferedImage(imgsel.getWidth(), imgsel.getHeight(),
       imgsel.getType());
        Color colorImagen = null; int red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < imgsel.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (imgsel.getHeight()-1); j++) {
                colorImagen = new Color(imgsel.getRGB(i, j));
                try {
                red = (int)(colorImagen.getRed() * 0.393 +
          colorImagen.getGreen() * 0.769 + colorImagen.getBlue() * 0.189);
                green = (int)(colorImagen.getRed() * 0.349 +
           colorImagen.getGreen() * 0.686 + colorImagen.getBlue() * 0.168);
                blue = (int)(colorImagen.getRed() * 0.272 +
          colorImagen.getGreen() * 0.534 + colorImagen.getBlue() * 0.131);
                colorImagen = new Color((red>255)?255:red,
         (green>255)?255:green, (blue>255)?255:blue);
                } catch (Exception e) {}                    
                bi.setRGB(i, j, colorImagen.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    return bi;
}

public BufferedImage aplicarFiltroRGB() {
BufferedImage bi = null;
if (imgsel != null) {
 bi = new BufferedImage(imgsel.getWidth(), imgsel.getHeight(),
 imgsel.getType());
 for (int x = 0; x < imgsel.getWidth(); x++) {
 for (int y = 0; y < imgsel.getHeight(); y++) {
 Color c = new Color(imgsel.getRGB(x, y));
 int r = c.getRed();
 int g = c.getGreen();
 int b = c.getBlue();
 bi.setRGB(x, y, new Color(g, b, r).getRGB());
  }
 }
  }
  return bi;
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new menuu().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Agrego a continuación la clase MET, que me faltó agregar:

```
   ´´´
import java.io.*;

public class MET
{
FileInputStream entrada;
FileOutputStream salida;
}

public MET()
{

}
public byte [] AbrirImage(File archivo)
{
byte [] bytesImg = new byte[1024*100];
try
{
entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);
entrada.read(bytesImg);
}
catch (IOException e)
{

}
return bytesImg;
}

public String GuardarIMG (File archivo, byte[] bytesImg
{
String respuesta = null;
try 
{
salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
salida.write(bytesImg);
respuesta = "La imagen se guardó con éxito";
}
catch (IOException e)
{

}
return respuesta;
}
}
```

´´´

Comment: Volvenos al principio, no está cargando la imagen,verifica que la ruta es correcta. (elimmina los 5 primeros comentarios para que no nos censuren ).

Comment: La imagen se encuentra en bytesImg, luego se crea un array de bytes que se guarda en "is", para después ser leída por newBi que es lo que busco imprimir (lo cambié a como está en la publicación) pero el error es el mismo, ¿me estoy pasando por alto algo?

Comment: Fijate que en MET, tenes el método **AbrirImage** y cuando lo llamas desde **jButton1ActionPerformed** usas **AbrirImagen**, probablemente ese sea el problema... una "n".

Comment: No, sí es AbrirImagen, se me pasó una n a la hora de pegar